# javascript convert a date to local timezone

Tags: javascript

I have a function that returns a date object. how do I convert this to the local timezone of the user? the user may be anywhere so it can't be hard coded.

```
 getNextDay = (dayIndex) => {
  const today = new Date();
  today.setDate(
    today.getDate() + ((dayIndex - 1 - today.getDay() + 7) % 7) + 1
  );
  today.setHours(17, 30, 0);
  return today;
};
```

Comment: If your code is running in the browser, creating a `new Date` gives you the date in the browser's user's time zone.

Comment: @PatrickHund I am setting the hours so I need that converted

Comment: Do you mean to get it as a string instead of time? Like today.toLocaleString() ?

Comment: hi @hitodo9051, it's possible to convert to a different timezone with vanilla js. But why not use a third party library like momentJS to do the convertion